# In django models how to update a particular column after creating

Tags: django, django-models, django-serializer

I have models.py as below,

```
class members(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    HID = models.IntegerField(blank=False,unique=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    member_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False, default='')
    father_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False, default='')
    wife_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False, default='')
```

Now in the above HID value is entered manually each time.
When there is a new member is getting inserted I am planing to enter my previous member HID value after which the insertion should be done, so that all entries after that should be updated with HID + 1.

I tried to implement this with linked list model like having one more with next_HID= , but here the issue is my insertion is very less like yearly one or 2 but query is more so then each time this list has to be created by doing query. so I thought to update the HID number each time after insert.

Please let me know how can I run an update query after every insert in django models for the above purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as this:

```
members.objects.filter(HID__gt=new_member_HID).order_by('-HID').update(HID=F('HID')+1)
```

If you are using the class-based views from Django Rest Framework, then you can add this line right below

```
serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
```

by overriding the method `create` of your [CreateAPIView](http://www.cdrf.co/3.1/rest_framework.generics/CreateAPIView.html#create)

Use the `HID` that's in `request.data`

Comment: do I have to add this in models.py or in views.py (i.e in "class MemberCreate(generics.CreateAPIView))

Comment: If you really do this only once per year or so, I would just do it on the shell. python manage.py shell ... from appname.models import members ... members.create( ...

Comment: No we cant use backedend  as people who use this system doesn't know it.  @oregon Trail Can you please let me know where to execute this to update each time before insert . I am using "generics.CreateAPIView" to create API

Comment: Ok that is working , but what is F ? It says it is not defined do I need to import something for it?

Comment: sorry I have to import the F module in db.models. Django db models are really awsom!! reducing much work if we use  it properly.

Comment: I'm glad you found F : )

Comment: in this case when I make HID as unique it gives the following error during update query "django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: webapi_members.HID".  This happens when 2 tries to becom 3 already 3 exist and it doesn't allow. Is there any way where I can run the update from the last ?   The other option is fetch the max HID number then increase by 1 until it reaches my HID value. But instead is there any easy way?

Comment: yes that works partially, but update is not happening only till order works. So I put that into a loop with order then change value and save

Comment: If you're updating the records one by one in a loop your performance will suffer if you have 1000s of rows. Avoid this in the future.

Comment: @OrgonTrail is there any suggestion you have or any other logic to implement this concept.